# How to send a POST request in httpie including quotes?

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, httpie

I use httpie in the windows shell. My command looks like this:

```
http --form -v POST "http://192.168.1.1/set/time" category=Time settings={"timezone":"Universal","ntp":{"enable":"no"},"time":"11:19:53","date":"2018-10-31"}
```

However, the json value is transmitted without quotes:

```
{timezone:Universal,ntp:{enable:no},time:11:19:53,date:2018-10-31}
```

how can I transmit with quotes? Like:

```
{"timezone":"Universal","ntp":{"enable":"no"},"time":"11:19:53","date":"2018-10-31"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"` and `,` need to be escaped:

```
http [...] settings={^"timezone^":^"Universal^"^,^"ntp^":{^"enable^":^"no^"}^,^"time^":^"11:19:53^"^,^"date^":^"2018-10-31^"}
```